# How to configure this GridLayout correctly?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm sadly far from being an expert in SWT and RCP, but I really tried my best here... I can't figure out how to configure the widgets to get this layout (just a Photoshopped screen, never worked this way):

[image: expected screen]

This is what I get if I set the column number of the GridLayout to 2:

[image: 2 columns]

Here is the Refresh and the Blacklist button in the wrong row, but at least everything is visible...

And this is what I get if I set the column number of the GridLayout to 3:

[image: 3 columns]

This is total messed up... Most of the widgets are pushed outside the visible area. DatePicker, Refresh, Whitelist and the Calculate buttons are not visible, they are somewhere outside on the right.

This is the codepart for this screen area:

```
resultingProductsGroup = new Group(propProdGroup, SWT.NONE);
final GridData gd_resultingProductsGroup = new GridData(SWT.FILL,
        SWT.CENTER, true, false);
gd_resultingProductsGroup.widthHint = 240;
resultingProductsGroup.setLayoutData(gd_resultingProductsGroup);
resultingProductsGroup.setText("Resulting products");
final GridLayout gridLayout_4 = new GridLayout();
gridLayout_4.numColumns = 2;
resultingProductsGroup.setLayout(gridLayout_4);

Label refDateLabel = new Label(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.NONE);
refDateLabel.setText("Reference date:");

refDateInput = new DateInput(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.BORDER);
refDateInput.setLayoutData(new GridData());

refDateInput.setValue(new Date());

calculateProductsButton1 = new Button(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.NONE);
setupImageButton(calculateProductsButton1, Images.getButtonRefresh());
calculateProductsButton1.setLayoutData(new GridData());
GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().hint(18, 18).applyTo(
        calculateProductsButton1);

resultingProductsTable = new TableListWidget<Product>(
        resultingProductsGroup, SWT.BORDER, ListWidgetMode.MULTI);
resultingProductsTable.setLinesVisible(true);
resultingProductsTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
final GridData rpTableProperty = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
        true, 3, 1);
resultingProductsTable.setLayoutData(rpTableProperty);

GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().hint(230, 240).applyTo(
        resultingProductsTable);


setupResultingProductsTableColumns();
resultingProductsTable.sortByComparator(new Comparator<Product>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
        return o1.getPartNum().getExternalId().compareTo(
                o2.getPartNum().getExternalId());
    }
});
resultingProductsTable.addOpenListener(new IOpenListener() {
    @Override
    public void open(OpenEvent event) {
        doResultingProductsTableOpen();
    }
});

calculateProductsButton2 = new Button(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.NONE);
calculateProductsButton2.setText("Calculate");

whitelistAddButton = new Button(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.NONE);
whitelistAddButton.setText("Whitelist");
whitelistAddButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        doAddToWhitelist();
    }
});

blacklistAddButton = new Button(resultingProductsGroup, SWT.NONE);
blacklistAddButton.setText("Blacklist");
blacklistAddButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        doAddToBlacklist();
    }
});
```

What am I not seeing here? I'm stuck with this GUI bug for over 2 days now... Please, help me :)

Comment: For a start the GridDataFactory applied to resultingProductsTable is overriding the plain GridData in the previous lines

Comment: So I should apply the width and height hints somehow else?

Comment: You can't mix `GridData` and `GridDataFactory` on a single control. Use one or the other

Comment: I will try that right in the morning. Do we expect the change to affect or solve the messed up layout?

Comment: Well you are losing the span over 3 columns of the table so that would make a big difference. Since this code isn't a [mcve] it is very difficult for anyone else to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could design the whole composite with one GridLayout and 3 columns, while using horizontal span of 3 on the table. That doesn't give you the desired mocked up screen though, because reference date controls and buttons at the bottom would be aligned in columns.

Try instead using 3 composites

- reference date: row layout
- table: fill layout
- button list: row layout